# Thevenin Equivalent With Two Voltage Sources

Tags: thevenin

I've been working through a few examples of Thevenin Equivalent circuits, and came across this one.

*Find the Thevenin Equivalent circuit as seen by a load resistance between points A and B.*

Finding the equiv. resistance wasn't too hard (75ohms), but I'm having trouble calculating the equiv. voltage.

I've attempted the questions, but am not sure I got the correct answer. Here's my working.

The total voltage of the circuit is 12V because of two aiding voltage sources being in series. From this, you can use a voltage divider between the two 150ohm resistors, getting a value of 6V. Another voltage divider can be used to find the voltage at node B, that being 2.4V.

Not sure I've done the next thing correctly -

I've assumed that Node A is 3V, and since the Thevenin voltage is the difference between Node A and B, Thevenin Voltage = 3-2.4 = 0.6V. Have I done this question correctly?

[image: Figure 1]

Anywho, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be trying to solve this as one problem. I would split it in 2 simple ones: 1) 9V + 150 ohm + 150 ohm  and 2) 3 V + 100 ohm. Now make Thevenin equivalent for each. What do you get ? for 1 you get 300 ohms in parallel with a current source and for 2 something similar. Now redraw your schematic and note how only node A and B are remaining making the problem trivial to solve.

Comment: There is not 12 V across the two 150 ohm resistors.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon The source voltage is 12V, I don't think I mentioned there was 12V across the two 150 ohm resistors.

Comment: That means you are misunderstanding voltage dividers. The voltage between the two 150 ohms is not 6 V.

Comment: Oh, my bad! The voltage divider should be 12 * ((150+100)/150 + 250) - giving 7.5V?

Comment: You are ignoring the presence of Rload ! If you insist on treating this as a voltage divider (thus solving it the hard way) then do it properly and account for Rload and the 3 V at the other side of Rload.

Comment: Ah sorry for being frustrating, I'm taking my first electronics subject at the moment, and have only been taught to solve this way (so far).

Comment: You ask a question about Thevenin equivalent, yet you try to solve it without using Thevenin ?!?! I propose a simple solution using Thevenin. Then look up what Thevenin theorem is and practise it on this circuit. It is not difficult.

Comment: I shall go and revise Thevenins - thanks for the help anywho.

Answer (score 6):

I think there was some confusion in the comments, so I'll write up an answer.

The circuit we're talking about is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faqViC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I've left out the load - it has nothing to do with your Thevenin equivalent.

Your goal is to make a circuit that looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGbeTk.png)</sup>

so you need to find two things: the equivalent resistance and the Thevenin voltage. You already found \$R_{eq} = 75 \Omega\$, so I won't go over that.

The Thevenin voltage of a circuit is the same as the *open circuit voltage*: when you leave the load disconnected, \$V_{th} = V_{ab}\$. That means that all you need to do is find \$V_a\$ and \$V_b\$ with no load.

\$V_a\$ is easy - it's just 3 V - so the harder part is
$$
V_b 
= (3V + 9V) \frac{100 \Omega}{150\Omega + 150\Omega + 100\Omega}
= 3 V
$$ 
so
$$
V_{th}
= V_a - V_b
= 0 V
$$

That means the Thevenin equivalent of this circuit is just a 75 ohm resistor - there's no voltage across the terminals.

Comment: This the correct method approaching a Thevenin/Norton problem, in every sense. The comments below the question made the problem more confusing for the asker than it should be.

Comment: I agree - there is no need to use the Thevenin transformations. It's usually much simpler to find any 2 of V_oc, I_sc, and R_eq.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon Thanks for clearing things up - may I ask though, what are Thevenin transformations? Has that something to do with the Norton Equivalent?

Comment: Exactly. You can switch back and forth between Thevenin and Norton equivalents without affecting the rest of the circuit. This lets you do some things more easily -- sometimes doing these transformations puts components conveniently in series/parallel -- but it's not really a bulletproof method.

Answer (score 0):

here we can use superposition theorem.when 9v is active and 3v is shorted,we should use voltage devider rule to find the voltage of 100 ohm.this is 9/4(B+ & A-).now,3v is active and 9v is shorted,we again use voltage devider rule to find the voltage of (150+150)ohm.this is 9/4(B- & A+).so totally v_th=9/4-9/4=0